# Textbox filter through SQL Datagridview - displaying too many columns (Duplicate Columns)

Tags: c#, mysql, search, datagridview, filter

The search method is here:

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-HNR3NJB\\mysql;Initial Catalog=stock;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ProductName FROM [stock].[dbo].[Products]", con);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("ProductName LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Now that does filter out the results in the table, but it adds columns like the picture below:

[Search Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vofqy.png)
Load data function (gets called as soon as the form is loaded:

```
public void LoadData()
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-HNR3NJB\mysql;Initial Catalog=stock;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();
        //reading data from sql
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [stock].[dbo].[Products]", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        foreach (DataRow item in dt.Rows)
        {
            int n = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[0].Value = item["ProductID"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[1].Value = item["ProductName"].ToString();
            if ((bool)item["ProductStatus"])
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "Active";
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[2].Value = "Inactive";
            }
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[3].Value = item["Employee"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[4].Value = item["CPU"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[5].Value = item["RAM"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[6].Value = item["SSD"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[7].Value = item["HDD"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[8].Value = item["WindowsVersion"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[9].Value = item["Description"].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[n].Cells[10].Value = item["Type"].ToString();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: It almost appears like you have defined those columns in the datagridview prior to setting the datasource. What does the datagridview look like before you run this section of code? Remark out the code, run the program and does the dgv have the other 4 columns?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/G3oc4

Above is the picture of my dataGridView1 columns and the datagridview BEFORE i search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so you're filling the datagridview elsewhere. You would just need to apply the rowfilter to the view to in the textbox_textchanged event

Where you're populating your current datagridview, ensure that you have your dt instantiated in a wider scope so that the textbox event can access it and then all you should have to do in your textchanged event is the following line:

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("ProductName LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.text);
```

This should then limit the rows to what is currently found.  Here's an example of a demo database (you will have to change this to suit your needs)

```
    DataTable dt; //declared outside a method so that multiple methods have access to it object.
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Some other area where the datagridview is populated with more information
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"MyConnectionString");
        con.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT FirstName, LastName, Address, State FROM Employee", con);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //all that should be needed to filter the datagridview to your condition
        dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("FirstName LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);

    }
```

Of course, you really need to switch to using statements so that the objects used are disposed of properly but this is to show more that the basic reason your grid is doing this is that you are applying another datasource into the grid and it doesn't know that you still want all the information you had prior just limited to rows that match your filter.

EDIT - FOR CLARIFICATION

Let's do this. In your loaddata code, remark out the entire for each loop. Add the following lines

```
datagridview1.columns.clear();
datagridview1.datasoure = dt;
```

This will hide your pre-existing columns for now without you having to do it manually.
And should show the grid with all the information from the query.

Then in your textchanged event remark all your code and replace it with the line I showed above that uses the DefaultView of the datatable (dt)

That should get you up and running. Once that's done, we can make a change to the query that will allow you to show 'Active'/'InActive' instead of the checkbox for the bit field.

Comment: Im so sorry mate, don't fully understand. Can you please take a look at update in original post.

Comment: Instead of iterating through the datatable that you populate, why not just assign it as the datasource. Then it's just a matter of filtering its default view.

Comment: Can i have an example? All the coding lang i'm not all that familiar with, ask me what all those lines do and I can tell you and i somewhat understand what they do, but i'm still new to the whole sql/data thing.Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Great to hear. Are you happy with the checkboxes for ProductStatus? Keeping them will alleviate any problems where you might want to update changes via the grid later. You could just rename the field to something like ProductActive so that a check is assume yes.